# Efficient way to search and count tags with MongoDB's new aggregation framework?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm experimenting with the new AF to migrate away from Map/reduce. I have millions of objects like this:

```
{
 _id: ObjectID,
 owner: 1,
 tags: [
   {text: "dog", score: 5}, 
   {text: "cat", score: 3}, 
   {text: "hamster", score:1}]
}

{
 _id: ObjectID,
 owner: 2,
 tags: [
   {text: "cat", score: 8}, 
   {text: "fish", score: 4}]
}
```

and I want to do a report with count of all matches of "cat" and "fish" where the owner is X.

So far I have my pipeline assuming input tags ["cat", "fish"] looking like:

```
{
  $match: { owner: X, $in: {"tags.text": ["cat", "fish"]}}
}, {
  $project: {text: "$tags.text"},
}, {
  $unwind: "$text",
}, {
  $match: {"text": {$in: {"tags": ["cat", "fish"]}}
}, {
  $group: {"_id": "$text", "total: {"$sum": 1}}
}
```

The first $match is to just narrow down to a subset of all these million objects - since I have an index on owner and "tags.txt".

This pipeline functions fine for small numbers of tags, but I need to be able to pass in 100-1000 "tags" and get a quick result. It seems to be that it must be inefficient to project out and unwind all the tags, only to filter way 90% in the next match step.

Is there a more efficient way? Maybe reorder the pipeline steps?

Comment: Just BTW, I have converted some of my simple MapReduce calls to this framework and in one case I get the same result in 1/10th the time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks good to me except for some typos and the usage of the `$in` operator in each `$match` pipeline operation probably should read:

```javascript
{
  $match: {owner: X, "tags.text": {$in: ["cat", "fish"]}}
}, {
  $project: {text: "$tags.text"}
}, {
  $unwind: "$text"
}, {
  $match: {"text": {$in: ["cat", "fish"]}}
}, {
  $group: {"_id": "$text", "total": {"$sum": 1}}
}
```

In essence, you want to use `$match` as early in the pipeline as possible to limit the number of documents being processed later in the pipeline.  The match on `owner` and specific tags accomplishes this.  You also need to make sure your `$match`, the equivalent of a `.find()`, uses the appropriate indexes.